# React + Recharts legend not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, data-visualization, recharts

I am using React + Recharts to create a stacked and grouped bar chart, it is my first time using Recharts. but the legend is not working properly, I want the legend to toggle both graphs in each group, but it is only working for the left side bar and not for the right side bar.
is it possible to make it work for both?

[image]

I did it like this:

```js
const selectBar = event => {
  let updatedLabels = [];
  let updatedLabelsSpend = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.labels.length; i++) {
    let label = data.labels[i];
    let spendLabel = data.filteredDataSpend[i];

    if (label.key !== event.value) {
      updatedLabels.push(label);
      updatedLabelsSpend.push(spendLabel);
    } else {
      if (/\s/.test(label.key) && /\s/.test(spendLabel.key)) {
        let newLabel = { key: label.key.trim(), color: label.color };
        let newLabelSpend = {
          key: spendLabel.key.trim(),
          color: spendLabel.color,
        };
        updatedLabels.push(newLabel);
        updatedLabelsSpend.push(newLabelSpend);
      } else {
        let newLabel = { key: label.key + ' ', color: label.color };
        let newLabelSpend = {
          key: spendLabel.key + ' ',
          color: spendLabel.color,
        };
        updatedLabels.push(newLabel);
        updatedLabelsSpend.push(newLabelSpend);
      }
    }
  }
  setData({ ...data, labels: updatedLabels });
};
```

you can check the demo in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-stallman-c3t2g)

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the state update for `filteredDataSpend`, this little change fix it

```
    setData({
      ...data,
      labels: updatedLabels,
      filteredDataSpend: updatedLabelsSpend
    });
```

Comment: oh my Godness, how I forgot it, I just realised, thanks